# typeahead.js showing all results instead of just matching results

Tags: javascript, typeahead, bloodhound

I'm having trouble getting typeahead.js to return only results that match the inputted query. For example, if I type in "Facebook" to my company search bar, it will return all companies ("Yahoo", "Google", etc.) even though most of these don't match the query. I am not doing any server side processing of data. Should my datumTokenizer function take care of this filtering?

Also, I notice that every time I modify the query, it enters the filter() function for each datum. So when I change the query from "G" to "Go," the console.log() statement in filter: function (companies_list) will print 3000 times.

Here is my code:

```
var companies = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.name);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: '/json/company_list.json',
      filter: function (companies_list) {
        // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
        return $.map(companies_list, function (company) {
          console.log('mapping')
          return {
            name: company.name
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
  var promise = companies.initialize();
  promise.done(function() {console.log('Bloodhound initialized!')});

  // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
  // options being used
  $('#form-company').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'companies',
    displayKey: 'name',
    // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
    // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
    source: companies.ttAdapter()
  });
```

And an example of what my url is returning:

```
[{"name": "Yahoo"}, {"name": "Sanchai Technologies "}, {"name": "Oliver Wyman"}, {"name": "University of Oregon"}, ...]
```

I am using remote because prefetch absolutely does not work for me. It only gives me the suggestion [object Object], which makes no sense. I would like to use prefetch/remote to load the entire .json file upon initialization, and not make any further requests to the server. So I think prefetch is the better option of me (small file, 77kB), but it's just not working at all.

Thanks v much for the help!

Comment: What version of `typeahead` are you using?  I don't think `prefetch` works anymore fyi, see [Migrating to typeahead.js v0.10.0](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md).  I can't help with why all results are being returned with `remote`, i'm troubleshooting the same issue.

Comment: Any updates on getting only matching terms displayed?

Comment: Did you work this out? I get the same behaviour but only on a Bloodhound using a filter as you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing "Prepare". Try something like I did

```
var information = {
    url: urlRoot,
    prepare: function (query, settings) {
        settings.type = "POST",
        settings.url += '?prefix=' + query;
        return settings;
    }
};
var names = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('navn'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: information,

});
```

Or, you can look at my post there. It is only returning the result that a user enter into the text box. [My Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991387/search-operation-after-twitter-typeahead-autocomplete-asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The problem is that the remote URL returns a standard list, there's no ability to pass the query to it so that it returns a filtered subset that match the search term.
Because of this the filter implementation must handle filtering results so that they match the query.